# Stop animating a jpg

Tags: jquery

I have a url which produces a animated jpg. It has a js file attached which uses the property of top and left. Random values are assigned to the top and left. The entire script is pure javascript.[No `jQuery` is used or `jQuery animate`]

### What I want is

To stop the animation until I do a mouseover.

### My Code

```
$('#s0').live('mouseover',function(){
     var top = $(this).css("top");
     var left = $(this).css("left");
     $(this).css({top:top, left:left}).animate({top:top, left:left}); 
     console.log(top);
     console.log(left);
})
```

This only stop for about a second, since `animate` needs an argument to show the time in `ms` to keep alive the animation.

I tried add `setinterval` and `hover`.

### Constrains

I cant do any changes in the main js file. I have a write additional code to make this work.[Its a screwed up system, and I have to follow the rule.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#s0").on("mouseover", function(){
       $(this).stop();

}).mouseout(function(){
       $(this).animate(  ...  );  // animation continues...
})
```

Comment: ok, +1 for `on`.. How did I miss that.! But I need to keep that from animating and i need some logic on how to keep running that animate function without the time argument.

Comment: try this code. if its not what you want, its better to jsfiddle it. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score -2):

jQuery is now recommending that [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) be used instead of `live()` so you can swap those and then "The `off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()" ([from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/))

Comment: Sorry, it was late.  `on()` was correct by `off()` was just plain wrong